# Where are unpacked the files from a war with Wildfly

Tags: jboss7.x, wildfly

Usig Jboss or Wildfly, I can drop a `myapp.war` WAR file in the `deployments/` folder, or unzip it and create a `myapp.war/` directory (notice the weird .war extension for a directory).

With the later, I can edit my html and jsp files, and the server will respond accordingly.

But where will Wildfly unpack `myapp.war` with the first technique ? This may for exemple help to check that all files are in place in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, WAR files are not unpacked by default.  ShrinkWrap is now used to parse the archive.

If you want to edit these files, I would recommend continuing to create the `myapp.war/` folder, which you can do using a maven assembly.

Comment: Does it mean it's unpacked on memory or on the fly ?

Comment: In memory.  in fact, with the exploded war approach its also in memory they just scan for changes.

Comment: FWIW ShrinkWrap isn't used. VFS is still used.

Comment: It's possible, but it's not now.

Comment: The wars are then stored in \wildfly\standalone\tmp\vfs